# Passing through multiple parameters to rxjs operator

Tags: typescript, functional-programming, rxjs, observable

Is there a more elegant way of doing the following?

```
private getHeaders(): Observable<any> {
  let version;
  let token;
  return this.appInfo.getVersion()
    .pipe(
      tap(appVersion => version = appVersion),
      mergeMap(() => this.storage.get('access_token')),
      tap(accessToken => token = accessToken),
      mergeMap(accessToken => of(this.createHeaders(version, token)))
    );
}
```

How can I more *fluently* remember the two return values of `this.appInfo.getVersion()` and `this.storage.get('access_token')` without writing them to temporary variables with the power of rxjs?

Perhaps merging some observables into one?
There are so many rxjs operators and stuff...

Comment: [forkJoin](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html) is used exactly for that purpose.

Comment: Works! Thank you very much :)))) Please post an answer, so I can accept ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [forkJoin](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html), it's designed for this type of situation.

Answer (score 16):

Using `forkJoin`:

```
.pipe(
  mergeMap((appVersion) => forkJoin(
    of(appVersion),
    this.storage.get('access_token').take(1)
  )),
  mergeMap(([version, token]) => {
    this.createHeaders(version, token)
  })
)
```

But even easier with `withLatestFrom`:

```
.pipe(
  withLatestFrom(this.storage.get('access_token')),
  mergeMap(([version, token]) => {
    this.createHeaders(version, token)
  })
)
```

I have included both because `withLatestFrom` is easier but `forkJoin` should be used where you need to access the initial parameter. For example, if you were doing `this.storage.get(appVersion)`

Comment: forkJoin seems deprecated

Comment: forkJoin is not deprecated, it just takes an array now instead of comma separated args - the old comma separated args approach is deprecated

Answer (score 6):

You may want to try something like this

```
private getHeaders(): Observable<any> {
  return this.appInfo.getVersion()
    .pipe(
      mergeMap(version => this.storage.get('access_token')
                          .map(token => ({version, token})),
      map(data => this.createHeaders(data.version, data.token))
    );
}
```

**ALTERNATIVE VERSION WITH ZIP**

```
private getHeaders(): Observable<any> {
  const versionObs = this.appInfo.getVersion();
  const tokenObs = this.storage.get('access_token');
  return Observable.zip(versionObs, tokenObs)
    .pipe(
      map(data => this.createHeaders(data[0], data[1]))
    );
}
```

Comment: I think this should work, but it is not elegant imho... The two observable sequences could be done in parallel. Is `zip` the right tool for this?

Comment: You are right. You can `zip` too. I have updated the answer

Comment: With RxJS 5 you would use the resultSelector argument of mergeMap. In RxJS 6 the resultSelector is deprecated and they advice you to use "inner map" as an alternative. I think it's a matter of preference but I like the "map" option more than the "zip" option. But I may be biased because I'm mainly a C# developer...