# Passing params to withLatestFrom function

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngxs

I'm building store action. 
My store model looks like this:

```
{
    entities: {[n:number]: Client},
    ids: number[],
}
```

I fetch ids from backend that corresponds with given conditions. 
Then I need to fetch from backend those entities that are not in store yet.
But I don't know how to pass fetched ids to `withLatestFrom` function?

```
const params = {
    conditions,
    fields: ['id']
};
this.apiService.getList(params)
    .pipe(
    map(resp => {
      const ids: number[] = [];
      resp.map((item: Client) => {
        ids.push(+item.id);
      });
      return ids;
    }),
    withLatestFrom(this.checkEntities()), // how to pass ids ?
    tap(resp => {
      patchState({
        entities: resp[1],
        ids: resp[0],
        loading: false
      });
    })
    );

private checkEntities(ids: number[]) {
    const params: ApiWyszukiwarka = {
      conditions: {id: ids},
      fields: 'all'
    };
    return this.apiService.getList(params);
}
```

Or maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: withLatestFrom doesn't support params instead you can use switchMap and forkJoin together as documented here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49774676/passing-through-multiple-parameters-to-rxjs-operator

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just don't use `withLatestFrom` and have a look at `concatMap` instead.  `withLatestFrom` calls its callback on every emission from its source Observable while staying subscribed to all Observables passed as parameters but this is not what you need. You want to invoke `this.checkEntities()` only after you get the list of ids and then create a new Observable and subscribe to that.

So with `concatMap` you'll have something like this:

```
map(resp => {
  ...
  return ids;
}),
concatMap(ids => this.checkEntities(ids))
```

Comment: When I use `concatMap` I get `entities` as `resp` - not array of those two observalbes (entities and ids):/

Comment: This is obviously just the important part from your chain. I don't know what you want to do after getting ` this.checkEntities(ids)`

Comment: right I can `map` `checkEntities`  and combine result. Thanks

Comment: @piernik What did you mean by `map` `checkEntities` and combine the result?

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want to use `mergeMap` rather than `withLatestFrom`.

`mergeMap` allows you to map to an observable and then "unwrap" that observable.

```
this.apiService.getList(params)
    .pipe(
      map(resp => resp.map(item => +item.id),
      mergeMap(ids => this.checkEntities(ids)),
      tap(resp => {
        patchState({
          entities: resp[1],
          ids: resp[0],
          loading: false
        });
      })
    );
```

Comment: When I use `mergeMap` I get `entities` as `resp` - not array of those two observalbes :/